# request.security () on specific session ? ("1400-1500" D[1])

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking to get the high and low between 2pm and 3pm session of the previous day. I've been trying to recruit request.security (low[1], high[1]), it's on the whole day, but I can't seem to set a time interval for it, only on the "D". So, Is it possible to define a session in request.security ?

Here is a script without request.security where I display the range 2pm 3pm of the previous day

```
//@version=5
indicator('globex que today', overlay=true)

inputMax = input(265, title='ORB total time (minutes)')

//true affiche toutes les lignes
isToday = false

if year(timenow) == year(time) and month(timenow) == month(time) and dayofmonth(timenow) == dayofmonth(time)
    isToday := true
    

sess = input.session('1400-1500', title='Session Time')
t = time(timeframe.period, sess + ':1234567')
hide = timeframe.isintraday and timeframe.multiplier <= inputMax

is_newbar(res) =>
    ta.change(time(res)) != 0
in_session = not na(t)
is_first = in_session and not in_session[1]

orb_high = float(na)
orb_low = float(na)

if is_first
    orb_high := high
    orb_low := low
    orb_low
else
    orb_high := orb_high[1]
    orb_low := orb_low[1]
    orb_low
if high > orb_high and in_session
    orb_high := high
    orb_high
if low < orb_low and in_session
    orb_low := low
    orb_low

plot(isToday ? orb_high : na, style=plot.style_line, color=orb_high[1] != orb_high ? na : color.blue, title='ORB High', linewidth=2)
plot(isToday ? orb_low : na, style=plot.style_line, color=orb_low[1] != orb_low ? na : color.white, title='ORB Low', linewidth=2)
```

Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass a session information to the `security()` function. Your workaround solution is the way to go here.